# RUBY (Errno::ENOENT), no such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, mkdir

I'm following "The Bastards Book of Ruby" and I am trying to build a webscraper using nokogiri but about a quarter of the way into it when I attempt to run the code it throws the error:

```
Crawler.rb:6:in `mkdir': No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - data-hold/nobel (Errno::ENOENT)
from Crawler.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

My code is as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

DATA_DIR = "data-hold/nobel"
Dir.mkdir(DATA_DIR) unless File.exists?(DATA_DIR)

BASE_WIKIPEDIA_URL = "http://en.wikipedia.org"
LIST_URL = "#{BASE_WIKIPEDIA_URL}/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates"

HEADERS_HASH = {"User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}"}

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(LIST_URL))
rows = page.css('div.mw-content-ltr table.wikitable tr')

rows[1..-2].each do |row|

  hrefs = row.css("td a").map{ |a| 
    a['href'] if a['href'] =~ /^\/wiki\// 
  }.compact.uniq

  hrefs.each do |href|
    remote_url = BASE_WIKIPEDIA_URL + href
    local_fname = "#{DATA_DIR}/#{File.basename(href)}.html"
    unless File.exists?(local_fname)
      puts "Fetching #{remote_url}..."
      begin
        wiki_content = open(remote_url, HEADERS_HASH).read
      rescue Exception=>e
        puts "Error: #{e}"
        sleep 5
      else
        File.open(local_fname, 'w'){|file| file.write(wiki_content)}
        puts "\t...Success, saved to #{local_fname}"
      ensure
        sleep 1.0 + rand
      end  # done: begin/rescue
    end # done: unless File.exists?

  end # done: hrefs.each
end # done: rows.each
```

I have literally no idea why it is not creating a new directory to store the data in.  I know I must be missing something extremely simple...

Answer (score 6):

My best guess is that not only does "data-hold/nobel" not exist, "data-hold/" does not exist either. Since `mkdir` does not recursively create all parent directories of the directory you want to create, an error is thrown.

To fix this, you could use [FileUtils.mkdir_p](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p), which does create all parent directories.

Be sure to `include fileutils` before using `mkdir_p`.

Answer (score 3):

Bundled the requirements into a method with the proper debug message. Works as expected.

```
$:~/rubyterminals/file_tansfer$ cat mkdir_mthod.rb 
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'fileutils'

def run

my_dir="/home/rubyterminals/file_tansfer/new_dir"
create_a_directory(my_dir)

end


def create_a_directory(dir_name)

    if dir_name
      # dir_name was specified, ensure it is created and writable.
      unless File.exist?(dir_name)
        begin
          FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir_name)
           puts "just made the following dir #{dir_name}"
        rescue Errno::EACCES => e
          abort "Failed to create #{dir_name}: #{e.message}"
        end
      end
end
end

run
```

tested it :

```
-SVE1411EGXB:~/rubyterminals/file_tansfer$ ./mkdir_mthod.rb 

just made the following dir /home/rubyterminals/file_tansfer/new_dir
```

Hope this help.